# Makeup, make-up or make up?

Tags: nouns, proper-nouns

Make up course, make-up course, makeup course -

I mean something like make up course. I have to include this in my CV and I don't know which version is correct.

Comment: A look at a dictionary or two would answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR:
Make-up is the noun used when describing cosmetics.
Make up is the verb used when describing construction/creation or reconstruction.

Makeup and make-up are both nouns, and mean the same thing. These two are a case of [if hyphens should be used in compound words](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/889/when-is-it-necessary-to-use-a-hyphen-in-writing-a-compound-word). If used when referring to cosmetics, they both mean (from the OED):

> [make-up](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/112664), n.
>
> 4. d. *concr*.
>
>    Cosmetics, theatrical paint, etc., as used in making up the face, etc.

Make-up can also be used as an adjective to describe something that is intended to make something whole. For example, one may have missed work and has to do **make-up** hours to make up (verb, to be covered in the next section) missed work. This definition is as follows:

> [make-up](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/112664), adj.
>
> Designating something which serves to make up a required amount or whole, esp. in an industrial process; supplementary.

Make up can also be used as a verb, where is can mean to make up something that is incomplete or to make up something so that it is repaired or made good:

> [make up](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/112645?rskey=tO62Z0&result=1#eid1191754012), v.
>
> 3. a. *trans*. To make good, to compensate for (something that is wanting); to supply (a deficiency). Freq. also to make up (lost) ground .
>
>    b. *trans*. To supply the shortfall or deficiencies of; to complete (a given number, quantity, period, etc.); (formerly also in pass.) to be completed in form or growth, come to fruition, (occas.) to come to the end of one's life (obs.).
>
>    d. *intr*. To compensate for, atone for.
>
>    e. *trans*. *colloq*. to make it up to : to compensate or atone to (a person) for a loss or wrong suffered (esp. one of which the subject is the cause).

Make up as a verb can also be sued to mean create, construct, or otherwise put together:

> 1.*trans*. To build, erect (a tower, city, etc.). *Obs*.
>
> 2.*trans*. To build up (a bank, etc.) again where it has fallen away; to repair (an earthwork, fence, etc.) by making good any gaps or deficiencies. *Obs*.
>
> 5.*trans*. To close up (a letter) (obs.); to wrap up (an article); to put together into a parcel, package, or bundle.
>
> 6.*trans*. To compose, compile.
>
> 9.*trans*. To put together, construct, compound.

Additionally, the verb form can be used to describe the act of deciding:

> 11. *trans*. a. to make up one's mind (also to make one's mind up ): to reach or approach a decision or conclusion; to resolve (that, to do something).

Or for relationship mending:

> 12. *trans.* b. to make it up : to be reconciled after a dispute; to become friends again. Freq. with with. Also intr. in same sense, as make up (with).
>
>     c. To settle (a dispute, etc.); to end (a quarrel) by reconciliation.

And for imagine, or to create a story, character, etc. (make it up), this is covered under composition:

> 6. *trans.* c. To concoct, invent, fabricate (a story, lie, fictional scene or character, etc.); to compose (verses, etc.) impromptu; to improvise. Also to make (something) up as one goes along : to extemporize, improvise (something), freq. with little or no prior knowledge of the subject in question.

Comment: Finally finished that one (I think). So many meanings for this set of words.

Answer (score 1):

It's  chiefly makeup as a noun in AE, whereas it's make-up in BE. You cannot use make up here because it's a phrasal verb that also means to put makeup on somebody's face. For example:

She makes herself up every morning (The Free Dictionary).

Comment: When you say here, do you mean in this context, or in British English? Because in American English, make up class is a perfectly acceptable use, and is actually less ambiguous than make-up class, which might be either a course about cosmetics, or a class to replace (make up) a class you missed.

Comment: Karen, I mean you cannot say make up course.

Comment: @Karen You would either say "makeup course" or "make-up course", not "make up course".

Comment: http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/make-up_2?q=make+up

Comment: I'm going to assume regional differences, because I can, would, and have used make up course, but would never use makeup course unless I was talking cosmetics.

Comment: I'm going to assume some people in your area do not know the difference between a noun form used as a modifier and a phrasal verb.  That happens in my area too. Some people don't know there are rules about that; others know there's a rule but consistently get it backwards.

Answer (score 0):

Makeup and Make-up are both correct - although spell check may say otherwise.

In the UK, make-up is normally used:

[image]

[From the Boots page](http://www.boots.com/en/Beauty/Make-up/?affwin&awc=2041_1436963660_6b40e479d0c37e05e862229fbe908265&cm_mmc_o=-uubkbzfwlCjCKww5kbELCjCvi%20i9%20niioCjCC)

In the US, I think makeup is used:

[image]

[From the Sephora page](http://www.sephora.com/makeup-cosmetics)